# Linux Kernel tcp flow tcp_validate_incoming and RFC793

Tags: c, networking, tcp, linux-kernel, rfc

RFC 793, page 69 state that:

> first check sequence number
>
> ```
>   SYN-RECEIVED STATE
>   ESTABLISHED STATE
>   FIN-WAIT-1 STATE
>   FIN-WAIT-2 STATE
>   CLOSE-WAIT STATE
>   CLOSING STATE
>   LAST-ACK STATE
>   TIME-WAIT STATE
>
>     Segments are processed in sequence.  Initial tests on arrival
>     are used to discard old duplicates, but further processing is
>     done in SEG.SEQ order.  If a segment's contents straddle the
>     boundary between old and new, only the new parts should be
>     processed.
>
>     There are four cases for the acceptability test for an incoming
>     segment:
>
>     Segment Receive  Test
>     Length  Window
>     ------- -------  -------------------------------------------
>
>        0       0     SEG.SEQ = RCV.NXT
>
>        0      >0     RCV.NXT =< SEG.SEQ < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND
>
>       >0       0     not acceptable
>
>       >0      >0     RCV.NXT =< SEG.SEQ < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND
>                   or RCV.NXT =< SEG.SEQ+SEG.LEN-1 < RCV.NXT+RCV.WND
>
>     If the RCV.WND is zero, no segments will be acceptable, but
>     special allowance should be made to accept valid ACKs, URGs and
>     RSTs.
>
>     If an incoming segment is not acceptable, an acknowledgment
>     should be sent in reply (unless the RST bit is set, if so drop
>     the segment and return):
>
>       <SEQ=SND.NXT><ACK=RCV.NXT><CTL=ACK>
>
>     After sending the acknowledgment, drop the unacceptable segment
>     and return.
> ```

If I am not wrong the equivalent code can be found inside tcp_validate_incoming(...):

```
/* Step 1: check sequence number */
    if (!tcp_sequence(tp, TCP_SKB_CB(skb)->seq, TCP_SKB_CB(skb)->end_seq)) {
        /* RFC793, page 37: "In all states except SYN-SENT, all reset
         * (RST) segments are validated by checking their SEQ-fields."
         * And page 69: "If an incoming segment is not acceptable,
         * an acknowledgment should be sent in reply (unless the RST
         * bit is set, if so drop the segment and return)".
         */
        if (!th->rst) {
            if (th->syn)
                goto syn_challenge;
            if (!tcp_oow_rate_limited(sock_net(sk), skb,
                          LINUX_MIB_TCPACKSKIPPEDSEQ,
                          &tp->last_oow_ack_time))
                tcp_send_dupack(sk, skb);
        } else if (tcp_reset_check(sk, skb)) {
            tcp_reset(sk);
        }
        goto discard;
    }
```

However my question is with the following line in the RFC:

> ```
> If the RCV.WND is zero, no segments will be acceptable, but
> special allowance should be made to accept ***valid ACKs***, ***URGs*** and
> RSTs.
> ```

I can see that RSTs has been taken care of, in the if() statement, however I can't seems to figured out which part of the code process valid ACKs and URGs.

Any help is greatly appreciated !!

Comment: You don't seem to have looked very hard. What happens inside `tcp_sequence()`?  And what happens in the code in step 2?

Comment: step 2 is the equivalent code in RFC step 2, RST check and has nothing to do with ACKs or URGs ...

Comment: That's one answer to two questions.

Comment: tcp_sequence is basically doing the table check    (!before(end_seq, tp->rcv_wup) && !after(seq, tp->rcv_nxt + tcp_receive_window(tp));)   and has nothing to do with ACKs or URGs check